# Is there a way of effectively identifying/extracting headers from a table : Perl

Tags: php, xml, regex, perl, awk

I am trying to write up a perl script to generate a xml from a arbitrary tabular data which is available in a text file. For discussion sake lets say that I want to take the output from linux command

```
 df -k
```

and parse it to my perl script and generate a xml on the fly.

Sample check_disk_usage.log

```
 Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
 /dev/sda3             56776092   5431448  48413988  11% /
 /dev/sda1               101086     18993     76874  20% /boot
 tmpfs                  2021888         0   2021888   0% /dev/shm
```

Now in order to generate XML, I need to extract the headers from this table and store them in an array for later use(they will be used as opening and closing tags in the XML)
The way I am doing it :

```
 open my $file, '<', "$dir/check_disk_usage.log"; 
 my $firstLine = <$file>; 
 close $file; 

 my (@header) = $firstLine =~ /(\S+)/g;
```

i.e I am looking for all one or more non-whitespace patterns(effectively a word) and saving them in an array.
This is working fine as long as the the headers names follow the pattern of being single word

```
 eg Filesystem,1K-blocks,Used etc
```

However when a header name s.a "Mounted on" is encountered, it will break as both "Mounted" and "on" will be treated as different patterns and hence will be stored as different array elements.
Is there a way of effectively identifying/extracting headers from a table.

PS : I know, I could use awk to substitute the offending pattern with something and then parse the file. But then I would need to know the "offending pattern" before hand, which is not feasible as I plan to write this script for any arbitrary tabular data.

PSS : Although I am working with perl, I am open for other solutions as well(Eg php etc)

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I guess "Mounted on" is the only "bad" case you will find. No filenames have spaces in the name, so you can even hardcode this case.

Comment: If the data is truly arbitrary and cannot be captured by the general rules, then you're SOL without applying appropriate edge-case rules. Personally, I'd define the rules *per* output format consumed.

Comment: `unpack` and `substr` deal with fixed width data.

Comment: @fedorqui : You are right, in this case "Mounted on" is the only bad case. But as I mentioned, I am looking for a general solution.

Comment: What about splitting your header on tabs rather than generic spacing marks ? i.e. @header = split "\t",  $firstLine

Comment: @Pierre : Don't think that would work either as sometimes a single " " will also be a delimiter.Back to ground zero. Thanks

Comment: @fedorqui It is not the case that file names do not have spaces in them. That happens all the time.

Comment: The output of df (I realize that is just the example) is not guaranteed to be fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your data the values are separated where every line has whitespace on it. If some lines have whitespace and some don't then it isn't a delimiter. This leads to using a mask to determine where to split the header.

Kinda ugly, but:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Read the file provided on STDIN and then determine the delimiters,
# printing the individual elements per line.

my @lines = map { chomp; $_ } <>;

# The mask indicates if a character has ever been a NON whitespace character
my @mask  = ();

foreach my $line (@lines) {
    my @line = split //, $line;
    foreach my $index (0..$#line) {
        $mask[$index] ||= $line[$index] =~ /\S/;
    }
}

# At this point the mask indicates where to split based on the zeros within it.
# Want to turn this into substr ranges.
# So 000011110000 would become 4, 4

my @substrings = (); # will contain [from, length]
my $last_transition = 0;
my $last_value = $mask[0];

# When it transitions from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 the $last_transition is updated
# When the last value was a 1 it means it has stopped being a section and needs
# to be made into a split.
foreach my $index (1..$#mask) {
    if ($mask[$index] != $last_value) {
        if ($last_value) {
            push @substrings, [$last_transition, ($index + 1 - $last_transition)];
        }
        $last_transition = $index;
        $last_value = $mask[$index];
    }
}
# Handle the end of the line, which is considered a transition to 0
if ( $last_value ) {
    push @substrings, [$last_transition, ($#mask + 1 - $last_transition)];
}

# Just print them to show that it works, you would collect these instead.
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    foreach my $split (@substrings) {
        my $element = substr $line, $split->[0], $split->[1];
        $element =~ s/(?:^\s+|\s+$)//;
        print "$line -> $element\n";
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on -> Filesystem
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on -> 1K-blocks
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on -> Used 
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on -> Available
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on -> Use%
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on -> Mounted on
/dev/sda3             56776092   5431448  48413988  11% / -> /dev/sda3
/dev/sda3             56776092   5431448  48413988  11% / -> 56776092 
/dev/sda3             56776092   5431448  48413988  11% / -> 5431448
/dev/sda3             56776092   5431448  48413988  11% / -> 48413988 
/dev/sda3             56776092   5431448  48413988  11% / -> 11% 
/dev/sda3             56776092   5431448  48413988  11% / -> /
/dev/sda1               101086     18993     76874  20% /boot -> /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1               101086     18993     76874  20% /boot -> 101086 
/dev/sda1               101086     18993     76874  20% /boot -> 18993 
/dev/sda1               101086     18993     76874  20% /boot -> 76874 
/dev/sda1               101086     18993     76874  20% /boot -> 20% 
/dev/sda1               101086     18993     76874  20% /boot -> /boot
tmpfs                  2021888         0   2021888   0% /dev/shm -> tmpfs
tmpfs                  2021888         0   2021888   0% /dev/shm -> 2021888 
tmpfs                  2021888         0   2021888   0% /dev/shm -> 0 
tmpfs                  2021888         0   2021888   0% /dev/shm -> 2021888 
tmpfs                  2021888         0   2021888   0% /dev/shm -> 0% 
tmpfs                  2021888         0   2021888   0% /dev/shm -> /dev/shm
```

Obviously you would process the first line into elements rather than printing it out.